# Ejercicio SQL Listado de empleados

Tags: mysql, sql

Este es el ejercicio planteado: obtenga y visualice por pantalla un listado de los empleados que tengan un salario menor que la media del salario de los empleados de su departamento. Mostrar el nº de empleado, el apellido, el nº de departamento, y el salario. El listado estará ordenado ascendentemente por el nº de departamento. Y después otro ejercicio actualizar aumentado un 20% el salario de los empleados obtenidos en el ejercicio anterior. 
Estos dos son los que yo he intentado sin exito:
Primer ejercicio:

```
SELECT emp_no, apellido, dept_no, salario FROM empleados WHERE salario<(select AVG(salario) from empleados) order by dept_no asc;
```

Segundo ejercicio:

```
update empleados set salario = 1.20*salario;
```

Las tablas son las siguientes:
Tabla departamentos:
[image: Tabla departamentos]

Tabla empleados:
[image: Tabla empleados]

Dejo el sql de las tablas:

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `departamentos`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `departamentos`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `departamentos` (
  `dept_no` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `dnombre` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `loc` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dept_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `departamentos`
--

LOCK TABLES `departamentos` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `departamentos` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `departamentos` VALUES (10,'CONTABILIDAD','SEVILLA'),(15,'INFORMATICA','MADRID'),(20,'INVESTIGACION','MADRID'),(25,'RRHH','CUENCA'),(30,'VENTAS','BARCELONA'),(35,'I+D','ZAMORA'),(40,'PRODUCCION','BILBAO'),(45,'CALIDAD','ALICANTE'),(50,'LOGISTICA','SALAMANCA'),(55,'ADMINISTRACION','VALLADOLID'),(60,'MARKETING','GUADALAJARA'),(70,'INGENIERIA','ZAMORA'),(110,'COMPRAS','CACERES'),(120,'COMERCIAL','BARCELONA'),(127,'ALMACEN','SALAMANCA');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `departamentos` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `empleados`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `empleados`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `empleados` (
  `emp_no` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oficio` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dir` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_alt` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `salario` float(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comision` float(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dept_no` tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`),
  KEY `dept_no` (`dept_no`),
  CONSTRAINT `empleados_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`dept_no`) REFERENCES `departamentos` (`dept_no`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `empleados`
--

LOCK TABLES `empleados` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `empleados` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `empleados` VALUES (3456,'COTON','FRESADOR',7698,'2014-05-27',1000.00,100.00,25),(4455,'PEPE','VENDEDOR',7499,'2012-11-09',1500.00,10.00,10),(5432,'CIRUELO','ROMPEDOR',7839,'2017-12-30',1287.00,150.00,35),(6655,'RODRIGUEZ','ANALISTA',7698,'2012-11-15',3000.00,10.00,15),(7369,'SANCHEZ','EMPLEADO',7902,'1990-12-17',1050.00,NULL,20),(7499,'ARROYO','VENDEDOR',7698,'1990-02-20',1500.00,390.00,30),(7521,'SALA','VENDEDOR',7698,'1991-02-22',1625.00,650.00,30),(7566,'JIMENEZ','DIRECTOR',7839,'1991-04-02',2910.00,NULL,20),(7654,'MARTIN','VENDEDOR',7698,'1991-09-29',1600.00,1020.00,30),(7698,'NEGRO','DIRECTOR',7839,'1991-05-01',3005.00,NULL,30),(7782,'CEREZO','DIRECTOR',7839,'1991-06-09',3005.00,NULL,10),(7788,'GIL','ANALISTA',7566,'1991-11-09',2500.34,NULL,20),(7839,'REY','PRESIDENTE',NULL,'1991-11-17',500.00,10.00,25),(7844,'TOVAR','VENDEDOR',7698,'1991-09-08',1350.00,0.00,30),(7876,'ALONSO','EMPLEADO',7788,'1991-09-23',1440.00,NULL,20),(7900,'JIMENO','EMPLEADO',7698,'1991-12-03',1335.00,NULL,30),(7902,'FERNANDEZ','ANALISTA',7566,'1991-12-03',3010.00,NULL,20),(7934,'MUÑOZ','EMPLEADO',7782,'1992-01-23',1810.00,NULL,10),(8000,'LOPEZ','PESCADOR',7900,'2012-10-23',700.00,200.00,40),(9000,'MARCOS','FRESADOR',7876,'2012-10-23',700.00,200.00,40);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `empleados` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2020-02-04 13:13:45
```

Comment: Las pregunas pidiendo ayuda con tarea escolar deben incluir el enunciado del problema, un resumen del trabajo realizado hasta el momento y una descripción de los problemas o dificultades que se estén encontrando. Lee [ask] y visita el [tour] para más información.

Comment: por favor no edites una pregunta para cambiar el problema original. Eso hace que las preguntas existentes dejen de tener sentido. Si tienes una nueva pregunta debes crear una publicación. Lee [ask] y visita el [tour] para más información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como en este caso cada departamento tiene un sueldo medio diferente, al selecccionar debes tener en cuenta a qué departamento pertenece el empleado y cúal es el promedio de dicho departamento, esto se hace implementando una condición en el `select` anidado, utilizando alias de la tabla empleado para la comparativa.

A partir de aquí sólo tendrías que añadir que los empleados cumplan esta condión para aumentarles el sueldo con la correspondiente clausula `where` en la sentencia de `update`.

Ejemplo del `select`:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE `departamentos` (
  `dept_no` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `dnombre` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `loc` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dept_no`)
);

INSERT INTO `departamentos` VALUES (10,'CONTABILIDAD','SEVILLA'),(15,'INFORMATICA','MADRID'),(20,'INVESTIGACION','MADRID'),(25,'RRHH','CUENCA'),(30,'VENTAS','BARCELONA'),(35,'I+D','ZAMORA'),(40,'PRODUCCION','BILBAO'),(45,'CALIDAD','ALICANTE'),(50,'LOGISTICA','SALAMANCA'),(55,'ADMINISTRACION','VALLADOLID'),(60,'MARKETING','GUADALAJARA'),(70,'INGENIERIA','ZAMORA'),(110,'COMPRAS','CACERES'),(120,'COMERCIAL','BARCELONA'),(127,'ALMACEN','SALAMANCA');

CREATE TABLE `empleados` (
  `emp_no` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oficio` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dir` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_alt` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `salario` float(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comision` float(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dept_no` tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`),
  KEY `dept_no` (`dept_no`),
  CONSTRAINT `empleados_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`dept_no`) REFERENCES `departamentos` (`dept_no`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ;

INSERT INTO `empleados` VALUES (3456,'COTON','FRESADOR',7698,'2014-05-27',1000.00,100.00,25),(4455,'PEPE','VENDEDOR',7499,'2012-11-09',1500.00,10.00,10),(5432,'CIRUELO','ROMPEDOR',7839,'2017-12-30',1287.00,150.00,35),(6655,'RODRIGUEZ','ANALISTA',7698,'2012-11-15',3000.00,10.00,15),(7369,'SANCHEZ','EMPLEADO',7902,'1990-12-17',1050.00,NULL,20),(7499,'ARROYO','VENDEDOR',7698,'1990-02-20',1500.00,390.00,30),(7521,'SALA','VENDEDOR',7698,'1991-02-22',1625.00,650.00,30),(7566,'JIMENEZ','DIRECTOR',7839,'1991-04-02',2910.00,NULL,20),(7654,'MARTIN','VENDEDOR',7698,'1991-09-29',1600.00,1020.00,30),(7698,'NEGRO','DIRECTOR',7839,'1991-05-01',3005.00,NULL,30),(7782,'CEREZO','DIRECTOR',7839,'1991-06-09',3005.00,NULL,10),(7788,'GIL','ANALISTA',7566,'1991-11-09',2500.34,NULL,20),(7839,'REY','PRESIDENTE',NULL,'1991-11-17',500.00,10.00,25),(7844,'TOVAR','VENDEDOR',7698,'1991-09-08',1350.00,0.00,30),(7876,'ALONSO','EMPLEADO',7788,'1991-09-23',1440.00,NULL,20),(7900,'JIMENO','EMPLEADO',7698,'1991-12-03',1335.00,NULL,30),(7902,'FERNANDEZ','ANALISTA',7566,'1991-12-03',3010.00,NULL,20),(7934,'MUÑOZ','EMPLEADO',7782,'1992-01-23',1810.00,NULL,10),(8000,'LOPEZ','PESCADOR',7900,'2012-10-23',700.00,200.00,40),(9000,'MARCOS','FRESADOR',7876,'2012-10-23',700.00,200.00,40);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT emp_no, apellido, dept_no, salario
FROM empleados e1
WHERE salario<
(SELECT AVG(e2.salario) FROM empleados e2 WHERE e2.dept_no=e1.dept_no) 
ORDER BY dept_no ASC;

| emp_no | apellido | dept_no | salario |
| ------ | -------- | ------- | ------- |
| 4455   | PEPE     | 10      | 1500    |
| 7934   | MUÑOZ    | 10      | 1810    |
| 7369   | SANCHEZ  | 20      | 1050    |
| 7876   | ALONSO   | 20      | 1440    |
| 7839   | REY      | 25      | 500     |
| 7499   | ARROYO   | 30      | 1500    |
| 7521   | SALA     | 30      | 1625    |
| 7654   | MARTIN   | 30      | 1600    |
| 7844   | TOVAR    | 30      | 1350    |
| 7900   | JIMENO   | 30      | 1335    |
```

---

**EDICIÓN** para incluir la `query` de `update`:

Para incrementar el sueldo de los trabajadores que cumplen esta condición usamos la misma condición, y para evitar el error de `mysql` que avisa de que no podemos usar la misma tabla en la `subquery` que en la `query` de `update` podemos sustituir esa tabla por una segunda `subquery` que la trae al completo.

```
UPDATE empleados e1
SET salario=1.20*salario 
WHERE e1.salario<
(SELECT AVG(e2.salario) FROM (SELECT * FROM empleados) e2 WHERE e2.dept_no=e1.dept_no);
```

Resultado:

```
SELECT emp_no, apellido, dept_no, salario
FROM empleados
ORDER BY dept_no ASC;

| emp_no | apellido  | dept_no | salario |
| ------ | --------- | ------- | ------- |
| 4455   | PEPE      | 10      | 1800    |
| 7934   | MUÑOZ     | 10      | 2172    |
| 7782   | CEREZO    | 10      | 3005    |
| 6655   | RODRIGUEZ | 15      | 3000    |
| 7369   | SANCHEZ   | 20      | 1260    |
| 7902   | FERNANDEZ | 20      | 3010    |
| 7876   | ALONSO    | 20      | 1728    |
| 7788   | GIL       | 20      | 2500.34 |
| 7566   | JIMENEZ   | 20      | 2910    |
| 7839   | REY       | 25      | 600     |
| 3456   | COTON     | 25      | 1000    |
| 7654   | MARTIN    | 30      | 1920    |
| 7698   | NEGRO     | 30      | 3005    |
| 7844   | TOVAR     | 30      | 1620    |
| 7521   | SALA      | 30      | 1950    |
| 7900   | JIMENO    | 30      | 1602    |
| 7499   | ARROYO    | 30      | 1800    |
| 5432   | CIRUELO   | 35      | 1287    |
| 8000   | LOPEZ     | 40      | 700     |
| 9000   | MARCOS    | 40      | 700     |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Esta perfecto @Carmen! Pero el problema ahora lo tengo en el update porque no me deja hacerlo sobre una subselect he intentado esto pero me da error: `update empleados set salario=1.20*salario where salario=(SELECT salario 
FROM empleados e1 
WHERE salario< (SELECT AVG(e2.salario) FROM empleados e2 WHERE e2.dept_no=e1.dept_no));`

Comment: @Jandro edito la respuesta para incluir el update

Comment: @Carmen no todas las preguntas deben responderse en el sitio. Por favor, evita responder a preguntas que no cuenten con un enunciado claro o que no se ajusten bien al formato/contenido del sitio. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro el estado actual de la pregunta no tiene nada que ver con la original, que mostraba tablas, datos e un intento de consulta, de hecho todos los datos referidos en la respuesta provienen de la pregunta original, por eso está contestada. Si se ha editado posteriormente para eliminar dicha información no está en mis manos ni en las de nadie que conteste.

Comment: @Carmen perdón, no me había dado cuenta de eso. Voy a dejar la pregunta como estaba antes. Gracias por el comentario y la corrección.