# Hacer un update de una subselect

Tags: mysql, sql

Hay que hacer una actualización en la que hay que incrementar un 20% el salario que se obtiene de esta sentencia en la que se obtendría un salario menor que la media del salario de los empleados de su departamento.:

```
SELECT emp_no, apellido, dept_no, salario 
FROM empleados e1 
WHERE salario< (SELECT AVG(e2.salario) FROM empleados e2 WHERE e2.dept_no=e1.dept_no) ORDER BY dept_no ASC;
```

He intentado esto pero el mysql me da errores todo el rato, he visto que se podría hacer con un alias pero también lo he intentado sin suerte, por mas que pienso y busco no se me ocurre otra forma de hacerlo:

```
update empleados set salario=1.20*salario where salario = (select salario FROM empleados e1 
WHERE salario< (SELECT AVG(e2.salario) FROM empleados e2 WHERE e2.dept_no=e1.dept_no));
```

Dejo el sql de las tablas:

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
--
-- Table structure for table `departamentos`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `departamentos`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `departamentos` (
  `dept_no` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `dnombre` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `loc` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dept_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Dumping data for table `departamentos`
--
LOCK TABLES `departamentos` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `departamentos` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `departamentos` VALUES (10,'CONTABILIDAD','SEVILLA'),(15,'INFORMATICA','MADRID'),(20,'INVESTIGACION','MADRID'),(25,'RRHH','CUENCA'),(30,'VENTAS','BARCELONA'),(35,'I+D','ZAMORA'),(40,'PRODUCCION','BILBAO'),(45,'CALIDAD','ALICANTE'),(50,'LOGISTICA','SALAMANCA'),(55,'ADMINISTRACION','VALLADOLID'),(60,'MARKETING','GUADALAJARA'),(70,'INGENIERIA','ZAMORA'),(110,'COMPRAS','CACERES'),(120,'COMERCIAL','BARCELONA'),(127,'ALMACEN','SALAMANCA');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `departamentos` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
--
-- Table structure for table `empleados`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `empleados`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `empleados` (
  `emp_no` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `apellido` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oficio` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dir` smallint DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_alt` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `salario` float(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comision` float(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dept_no` tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`),
  KEY `dept_no` (`dept_no`),
  CONSTRAINT `empleados_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`dept_no`) REFERENCES `departamentos` (`dept_no`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
--
-- Dumping data for table `empleados`
--
LOCK TABLES `empleados` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `empleados` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `empleados` VALUES (3456,'COTON','FRESADOR',7698,'2014-05-27',1000.00,100.00,25),(4455,'PEPE','VENDEDOR',7499,'2012-11-09',1500.00,10.00,10),(5432,'CIRUELO','ROMPEDOR',7839,'2017-12-30',1287.00,150.00,35),(6655,'RODRIGUEZ','ANALISTA',7698,'2012-11-15',3000.00,10.00,15),(7369,'SANCHEZ','EMPLEADO',7902,'1990-12-17',1050.00,NULL,20),(7499,'ARROYO','VENDEDOR',7698,'1990-02-20',1500.00,390.00,30),(7521,'SALA','VENDEDOR',7698,'1991-02-22',1625.00,650.00,30),(7566,'JIMENEZ','DIRECTOR',7839,'1991-04-02',2910.00,NULL,20),(7654,'MARTIN','VENDEDOR',7698,'1991-09-29',1600.00,1020.00,30),(7698,'NEGRO','DIRECTOR',7839,'1991-05-01',3005.00,NULL,30),(7782,'CEREZO','DIRECTOR',7839,'1991-06-09',3005.00,NULL,10),(7788,'GIL','ANALISTA',7566,'1991-11-09',2500.34,NULL,20),(7839,'REY','PRESIDENTE',NULL,'1991-11-17',500.00,10.00,25),(7844,'TOVAR','VENDEDOR',7698,'1991-09-08',1350.00,0.00,30),(7876,'ALONSO','EMPLEADO',7788,'1991-09-23',1440.00,NULL,20),(7900,'JIMENO','EMPLEADO',7698,'1991-12-03',1335.00,NULL,30),(7902,'FERNANDEZ','ANALISTA',7566,'1991-12-03',3010.00,NULL,20),(7934,'MUÑOZ','EMPLEADO',7782,'1992-01-23',1810.00,NULL,10),(8000,'LOPEZ','PESCADOR',7900,'2012-10-23',700.00,200.00,40),(9000,'MARCOS','FRESADOR',7876,'2012-10-23',700.00,200.00,40);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `empleados` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
-- Dump completed on 2020-02-04 13:13:45
```

Comment: te edité la respuesta en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/354836/ejercicio-sql-listado-de-empleados/354837#354837, ya la tienes contestada

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Ejercicio SQL Listado de empleados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/354836/ejercicio-sql-listado-de-empleados)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba así, con un `JOIN` el MySQL es algo más permisivo:

```
UPDATE empleados JOIN (
    SELECT emp_no FROM empleados JOIN (
        SELECT dept_no,AVG(salario) salario_medio
          FROM empleados
          GROUP BY 1  
      ) c1 USING(dept_no)
      WHERE salario<salario_medio  
  ) c2 USING(emp_no)
  SET salario=salario*1.2;
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para poder completar la respuesta lo mejor posible.